# Webcam in Internet Explorer Uses .SWF file which is giving 404

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, flash, webcam

I am using Angular 4 with webcam library "**ack-angular-webcam**" its working fine in Google chrome, Firefox as in these browsers it uses getUserMedia() function but in Internet Explorer it still uses flash and .swf file is throwing 404. Interesting thing is it was working fine 1 month back.I didn't made any changes to the code.
below is the options i am providing.

```
options = {
      audio: false,
      video: true,
      // force_flash: false,
      // fallback: false, // force flash
      width: 400,
      height: 320,
      fallbackMode: 'callback',
      fallbackQuality: 500,
      fallbackSrc: 'fallback/jscam_canvas_only',
      cameraType: 'back'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy Jscam_canvas_only.swf from ack-angular-webcam to a location your server can serve.

```
options = {
      audio: false,
      video: true,
      // force_flash: false,
      // fallback: false, // force flash
      width: 400,
      height: 320,
      fallbackMode: 'callback',
      fallbackQuality: 500,
      fallbackSrc: 'assets/fallback/jscam_canvas_only',
      cameraType: 'back'
}
```